# Is it possible to disable, fade or make a button inside a dialog unclickable in GTK?

Tags: c, button, gtk

I have a dialog like this:

```
GtkWidget *dialog = gtk_dialog_new_with_buttons("Spell Checking", NULL, 0,
                                                GTK_STOCK_OK,
                                                GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,
                                                GTK_STOCK_ADD,
                                                GTK_RESPONSE_APPLY,
                                                GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,
                                                GTK_RESPONSE_REJECT,
                                                NULL);
```

After adding all the other necessary elements it'll look like this:

[image: Spell Check Dialog]

What I want to do is to disable the `OK` button if the list of correct words is empty.

Of course, there are workarounds like creating a dialog:

- with `OK` when then the list is not empty
- without otherwise

Nevertheless, **I would like to know if I can just disable/fade a buttoon and how.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GTK Widgets usually have a property `Sensitive`, when it's set to false, the widget grayed out, i.e. an user couldn't  interact with it. There's [a function for that purpose](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-sensitive)

```
void
gtk_widget_set_sensitive (GtkWidget *widget,
                          gboolean sensitive);
```

Also you could try to set it directly, like `myButton->Sensitive = false`.

Comment: That's right! - The keywords I couldn't come up with were *sensitive* and *to sensitize*.